# tengo un error ejecutar mi base de datos en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS bdtarea;
use bdtarea;

/*creando bd Clientes*/

CREATE TABLE Clientes(
        CLI_id int(11) not null auto_increment  comment 'Clave Primaria',
        CLI_nombres varchar(20) not null,
        CLI_apellidos varchar(20) not null,
        CLI_correo varchar(60) not null,
        CLI_direccion varchar(20) not null,
        CLI_dni char(8) not null,
        CLI_telefono char(9) not null,
        CLI_movil char(9) not null,
        CLI_sexo varchar(9) not null,
        CLI_fechaNac datetime not null,
        primary key (CLI_id),
        unique key (CLI_dni)
),
/*creando bd Dueños*/
CREATE TABLE Dueños(
        DUE_id int(11) not null,
        DUE_nombres varchar(20) not null,
        DUE_apellidos varchar(20) not null,
        DUE_correo varchar(60) not null,
        DUE_direccion varchar(20) not null,
        DUE_dni char(8) not null,
        DUE_telefono char(9) not null,
        DUE_movil char(9) not null,
        primary key (DUE_id),
        unique key (DUE_dni)
),
/*creando bd Marcas*/
CREATE TABLE Marcas(
        MAR_id int(11) not null,
        MAR_Descripcion longtext,
        primary key(MAR_id),
),
/*creando bd Tipos*/
CREATE TABLE Tipos(
         TIP_id int(11) not null
         TIP_Descripcion longtext,
         primary key (TIP_id),
),
/* Creando bd vehiculos*/
create table vehiculos(
         NroPlaca int(11) not null,
         VEH_color varchar(15) not null,
         VEH_modelo varchar(30) not null,
         VEH_AñoFab int(4) not null,
         CLI_id int(11) not null,
         DUE_id int(11) not null,
         TIP_id int(11) not null,
         MAR_id int(11) not null,
         primary key (NroPlaca),
         unique key (DUE_id)
         foreign key(CLI_id) references Clientes(CLI_id)
         foreign key(DUE_id) references Dueños(DUE_id)
         foreign key(TIP_id) references Tipos(TIP_id)
         foreign key(MAR_id) references Marcas(MAR_id)
);
/*creando bd Cochera*/
CREATE TABLE Cochera(
         COC_Nro int(11) not null,
         COC_Piso int(5) not null,
         COC_Disponibilidad varchar(10) not null,
         primary key (COC_Nro),
),
/*creando bd Estacionamiento*/
CREATE TABLE Estacionamiento(
         EST_Nro int(11) not null,
         EST_FechaEnt datetime not null,
         EST_FechaSalida datetime not null,
         EST_HoraEnt TIME not null,
         EST_HoraSalida TIME not null,
         EST_Costo int(4) not null,
         COC_Nro int(11) not null,
         NroPlaca int(11) not null,
         primary key (EST_Nro),
         foreign key(COC_Nro) references Cochera(COC_Nro)
         foreign key(NroPlaca) references Vehiculos(NroPlaca)
),
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes varios errore, por ejemplo:

- Despues de la definicion de algunas tablas terminas con , en lugar de ;
- Cuando sea el ultimo campo/referencia/foreign_key no finalices con , piensa que deberia de haber una definicion mas despues de la ,
- tienes varios foreign_keys definidos uno tras de otro sin poner diferenciarlos con ,

Te recomiendo definir linea por linea cada y asi visualmente sea mas sencillo identificar los detalles

```
CREATE TABLE Clientes (
    CLI_id INT ( 11 ) NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Clave Primaria',
    CLI_nombres VARCHAR ( 20 ) NOT NULL,
    CLI_apellidos VARCHAR ( 20 ) NOT NULL,
    CLI_correo VARCHAR ( 60 ) NOT NULL,
    CLI_direccion VARCHAR ( 20 ) NOT NULL,
    CLI_dni CHAR ( 8 ) NOT NULL,
    CLI_telefono CHAR ( 9 ) NOT NULL,
    CLI_movil CHAR ( 9 ) NOT NULL,
    CLI_sexo VARCHAR ( 9 ) NOT NULL,
    CLI_fechaNac datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( CLI_id ),
    UNIQUE KEY ( CLI_dni ) 
);

CREATE TABLE Dueños (
    DUE_id INT ( 11 ) NOT NULL,
    DUE_nombres VARCHAR ( 20 ) NOT NULL,
    DUE_apellidos VARCHAR ( 20 ) NOT NULL,
    DUE_correo VARCHAR ( 60 ) NOT NULL,
    DUE_direccion VARCHAR ( 20 ) NOT NULL,
    DUE_dni CHAR ( 8 ) NOT NULL,
    DUE_telefono CHAR ( 9 ) NOT NULL,
    DUE_movil CHAR ( 9 ) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( DUE_id ),
    UNIQUE KEY ( DUE_dni ) 
);
CREATE TABLE Marcas ( MAR_id INT ( 11 ) NOT NULL, MAR_Descripcion LONGTEXT, PRIMARY KEY ( MAR_id ) );
CREATE TABLE Tipos ( TIP_id INT ( 11 ) NOT NULL, TIP_Descripcion LONGTEXT, PRIMARY KEY ( TIP_id ) );
/* Creando bd vehiculos*/
CREATE TABLE vehiculos (
    NroPlaca INT ( 11 ) NOT NULL,
    VEH_color VARCHAR ( 15 ) NOT NULL,
    VEH_modelo VARCHAR ( 30 ) NOT NULL,
    VEH_AñoFab INT ( 4 ) NOT NULL,
    CLI_id INT ( 11 ) NOT NULL,
    DUE_id INT ( 11 ) NOT NULL,
    TIP_id INT ( 11 ) NOT NULL,
    MAR_id INT ( 11 ) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( NroPlaca ),
    UNIQUE KEY ( DUE_id ) ,
    FOREIGN KEY ( CLI_id ) REFERENCES Clientes ( CLI_id ), 
    FOREIGN KEY ( DUE_id ) REFERENCES Dueños ( DUE_id ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( TIP_id ) REFERENCES Tipos ( TIP_id ), 
    FOREIGN KEY ( MAR_id ) REFERENCES Marcas ( MAR_id ) 
);

CREATE TABLE Cochera (
    COC_Nro INT ( 11 ) NOT NULL,
    COC_Piso INT ( 5 ) NOT NULL,
    COC_Disponibilidad VARCHAR ( 10 ) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( COC_Nro )
);

CREATE TABLE Estacionamiento (
    EST_Nro INT ( 11 ) NOT NULL,
    EST_FechaEnt datetime NOT NULL,
    EST_FechaSalida datetime NOT NULL,
    EST_HoraEnt TIME NOT NULL,
    EST_HoraSalida TIME NOT NULL,
    EST_Costo INT ( 4 ) NOT NULL,
    COC_Nro INT ( 11 ) NOT NULL,
    NroPlaca INT ( 11 ) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( EST_Nro ),
  FOREIGN KEY ( COC_Nro ) REFERENCES Cochera ( COC_Nro ) ,
  FOREIGN KEY ( NroPlaca ) REFERENCES Vehiculos ( NroPlaca ) 
);
```

Comment: Esta es la solución correcta ya que cuando cierras la tabla pone ), y es ); como el chico o chica de esta solución por lo que marcala como correcta